# Android: Get height/width from byte array or file

Tags: java, android, bitmap, height, width

I have an image that is stored as a byte array (can also be accessed from Android directory as a .jpg) and I'm trying to get the width and height of the image. I've tried to use javax.imageio however Dalvik doesn't support this lib, so I've opted to use Bitmap. Can anyone help me out here? I keep getting Null Pointer Exceptions.

```
public int getWidth(byte[] image) throws IOException{
    Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.toString());
    int imageWidth = bitmapImage.getWidth();

    return imageWidth;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: May you please state the stack trace of the exception? We can't help you if you don't.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(14818): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14818): java.lang.NullPointerException at MainActivity.getWidth(MainActivity.java:336)

Comment: What line is line 336?

Comment: int imageWidth = bitmapImage.getWidth();

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer.

Comment: I like your answer, unfortunately however, it has not solved my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `decodeByteArray(image)` instead of `decodeFile(new String(image))`. Info left for future reference:

`toString()` does not work with arrays (it returns some random string of characters). Since you pass an invalid string to `decodeImage`, it returns `null` to indicate that it was not found. Therefore, if you invoke a method on it, it results in a `NullPointerException`. If the byte array is encoded using a charset, instead of using `image.toString()`, use `new String(image)` which properly decodes the byte array.

Comment: Ahh I see. I've changed the code to: Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new String(image));  but still get a Null Pointer Exception on the same line - int imageWidth = bitmapImage.getWidth();

Comment: @LBran Do you know what charset `image` uses?

Comment: ...It... It worked. Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length); Thank you!!